# How to set a default parameter date for the beginning of the month to yesterday date

Tags: reporting-services

I have build an SSRS report. I set a default date parameters as following:
startdate : take the first day of the month.
EndDate  : take yesterday date.

This code for the beginning of the month 
`=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(0)`
This code for yesterdate date

`=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,-1,CDate(FormatDateTime(Now,DateFormat.ShortDate)))`

The date works perfectly until, a new month comes, the result will be like this:
startdate: 01. 5 2019
end date: 30. 4 2019

where it should be :
startdate: 01. 4 2019
end date: 30. 4 2019

how can i make sure if a new date comes , it will take the first day of the previous month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an `IIF` statement to check if today is the first day of the month.  The following expression should do what you need.

```
=IIF(DatePart(DateInterval.Day, Today()) = 1, 
     DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now())-1, 1), 
     DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1))
```

Comment: This solution adds unecessary conditional logic and is therefore sub-optimal.  Simply referencing yesterday's date as per my answer will always return the desired start of the month.

Comment: hi Steve! thank you so much, it works exactly as i want ! thank you.

Comment: @JamilaAl Glad I could help.  Please click the checkmark to indicate this was the correct answer so that others with the same issue can refer to the solution.

Comment: @Steve-o169 Sure.

Answer (score -1):

Just change your `StartDate` to reference yesterday's date:

```
=DateSerial(Year(Today.AddDays(-1)),Month(Today.AddDays(-1)),1)
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  It does exactly what is required?

Comment: hi iamdave, it sames you did not get my question . code you put for yesterday value only.

Comment: Your question states that on 2019/05/01, you want your start date to be 2019/04/01 and your end date to be 2019/04/30.  Your expression for yesterday will always work and is not the problem.  My answer shows you how to change your start date expression to return the date as you say you need it.  Either my answer is correct and you are misunderstanding things, or your question is not properly explaining your problem.